# REPLACE INTO only if both columns are the same

Tags: mysql, primary-key, sql-insert

**WHAT I WANT**

I want to `REPLACE INTO` my table only if both `column1` and `column2` are the same.  Otherwise it should INSERT INTO even if `column1` or `column2` is the same.

**WHAT I TRIED**

I made `column1` and `column2` PRIMARY KEYS.

My SQL statement...

```
REPLACE INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

It REPLACES instead of INSERTS even if just one of `column1` or `column2` is the same.

I tried to search for the answer but I don't know the proper language to get the proper results.

**EDIT**

I set up the primary keys with..

```
ALTER TABLE PKweight DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(id,season);
```

My table..

[image]

I replaced the `REPLACE INTO` with `INSERT INTO` and I got this error...

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'id' in
```

which tells me it is failing on the one duplicate of column `id`.

**EDIT 2**

The PHP/MYSQL code..

```
foreach($teamO as $tm){
    $stmt = "REPLACE INTO PKweight (id, season, name, toi, weight_toi, standing, rank) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $dbConnection->prepare($stmt)->execute(["$tm->id", "$tm->season", "$tm->name", "$tm->toi", "$tm->weight_toi", "$tm->standing", "$tm->rank"]);
}
```

**EDIT 3**

Besides the compound PRIMARY KEY on `id` and `season` I also had a UNIQUE INDEX on `id` as shown by the gray key in the phpmyadmin screenshot above.  I removed it by..

```
ALTER TABLE PKweight DROP INDEX id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried doing the same way you have mentioned but it is replacing and inserting based on the constraint created (two columns constraint) Created constraint on ID and First Name.

First I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Sakila.ReplacePrac (
Studentid INT(6) ,
Firstname VARCHAR(20),
Lastname VARCHAR(30) ,
Gender CHAR(1),
Primary key(Studentid, Firstname))  ;

insert into ReplacePrac 
select 1, 'Rob', 'Stark', 'M'  union all 
select 1, 'Ben', 'Stark', 'M'  union all  
select 2, 'Arya', 'Stark', 'F'  union all 
select 2, 'Tyrian', 'Lan', 'M' ;
```

Currently table has this data:

```
# Studentid, Firstname, Lastname, Gender
    1,          Ben,      Stark,   M
    1,          Rob,      Stark,   M
    2,          Arya,     Stark,   F
    2,          Tyrian,   Lan,     M
```

I added Replace into clause and I think it is replacing whenever ID and First name match and inserting whenever it does not match (meaning it is "AND" condition rather than "OR")

```
Replace into Replaceprac (StudentID, Firstname, Lastname, Gender) 
Values('1', 'Jon', 'Snow', 'M'), 
('1', 'Ben', 'Snow', 'M'), 
('2', 'Sansa', 'Startk', 'F'), 
('2', 'Tyrian', 'Ster', 'M')
```

It replaced whenever it got match between ID and first name and inserted when ever ID or first name did not match. If you see it replaced Ben Start to Ben Snow, Tyrian Lan to Tyrian Ster and inserted for Jon and Sansa even if ID were already existing.

```
# Studentid, Firstname, Lastname, Gender
      1,       Ben,       Snow,      M
      1,       Jon,       Snow,      M
      1,       Rob,       Stark,     M
      2,       Arya,      Stark,     F
      2,       Sansa,     Startk,    F
      2,       Tyrian,    Ster,      M
```

Comment: Thanks.  I must not have set up the primary keys properly?  I posted an edit if you time to look at it.  Hopefully it gives some clues.

Comment: @deanresin Thanks for Providing info, Can you share the script which you are using ?

Comment: I'm using MariaDB if that makes any difference.

Comment: Is it because column `id` is marked as an index (the gray key in phpmyadmin) by itself besides also being a compound primary key with column `season`?

Comment: I think I was INSERTing into my table the same data twice.  I'm working on confirming that now.  I marked your answer as solved because you pretty much confirmed the problem is somewhere in my code because my understanding of primary keys and replace into was correct.

Comment: It was actually a UNIQUE INDEX I had on column "id".  It was the gray key in the phpmyadmin screenshot.  I kept your answer though because the way I asked the question.